# RVO overwriting value in parameter before return

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++03

Compiling the following with xlC on AIX results in code that prints "2 2". On Linux with gcc and clang it reliably produces "3 3".

```
#include <iostream>

struct Numbers
{
    Numbers() : a(0) , b(0) { } 
    Numbers(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) { }

    int a;
    int b;
};

Numbers combine(const Numbers& a, const Numbers& b)
{
    Numbers x;
    x.a = a.a + b.a;
    x.b = a.b + b.b;
    return x;
}

Numbers make()
{
    Numbers a(1, 1);
    Numbers b(2, 2);

    a = combine(a, b);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    Numbers a = make();
    std::cerr << a.a << " " << a.b << "\n";
}
```

It looks to me like AIX is applying RVO to the return value of `combine`, so when I create `Numbers x`, it ends up overwriting my parameter `a` with the default initialised `x`.

Am I invoking some undefined behaviour here? I would expect that no modifications are made to `a` until after `combine(a, b)` has been evaluated and assigned to `a`.

This is with:
IBM XL C/C++ for AIX, V12.1 (5765-J02, 5725-C72)
Version: 12.01.0000.0012

Comment: I don't see UB here. Seems to be a compiler bug.

Comment: What happens if you add `std::cerr << a.a << " " << a.b << "\n";` into `make()`?

Comment: Have you tried `return combine(a, b);` directly ?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug to me as well. Currious;  Does the result change with/without optimization?

Comment: Printing `a` and `b` in `make()` also results in "2 2". If I `return combine(a, b);` directly it works fine. Additionally if I move the entire body of `make()` into `main()` this also fixes it, which suggests to me some kind of RVO bug with xlC. 

It seems to occur at any optimisation level.

Comment: Definitely looks like a bug then.

Comment: Seems like it's time for you to submit a bug report to IBM... :)

Comment: Great, I love it when it's IBM's fault. :) Will submit a bug report. Thanks all!

Comment: @Hamish Morrison When they respond to your bug report, post the result here. Regardless of whether they confirm or deny it's a bug, the reply will be useful info for future users seeing this question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the compiler is performing copy elision on the copy assignment(!) where it could really only do so on an initialization. Which is to say that the compiler is indeed overwriting the object associated with your parameter `a` when initializing `x`. Having an application of RVO (for some definition of RVO) to the return value of `combine` is itself not wrong. What is wrong is the target of the RVO (which should be a temporary in the scope of `make` and not the object associated with `a` in `make`).

Adding a user provided copy assignment operator should work as a workaround:

```
Numbers &operator=(const Numbers &other) { a = other.a; b = other.b; return *this; }
```